# Get URL for Sendgrid unsubscribe preferences

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Is there any way using the Sendgrid API to retrieve the link to a specific users subscription preferences?

I know that it's attached to the emails themselves, but I'd like to link to the page from within my app so they can change their preferences without having to receive an email.

I looked, but cannot find this option in their API docs, or mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed by Sendgrid support, this is not possible.

Their suggestion is to create my own subscription management if I want to do this.

Comment: That's awful. It would have been great if they created an endpoint to get user preferences url